# CSV python extracting 1 line name

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm just a newbie in python, and i really love coding. I got an excel file, and i want to extract the line which contains a particular word like: a

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
a 2 3 5 6 777 324
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
b 1 2 5 2 243 123
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
c 1 2 5 2 423 312
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to find out the line which contains letter b and extract it - line 2! how can i do it?

Comment: You just like to get first column of every row right??

Comment: no it's like i have to get the line which has the word A or B or C in it !

Comment: for ex: the question is you have to find which line has the word a or the number 777 and get it out for me !

Comment: just iter entire file using readline() and check if your word contains in each line.

Comment: how can i check and find out the line which contains my word ?

Answer (score 0):

if you like to get lines matching character 'a' can be written as

```
fp = open("file.csv","r+")
for line in iter(fp):
    if "a" in line:
        print "matched"
```